# Hibernate - get back persisted Object to get generated data

Tags: hibernate, persistence, entitymanager

I use Hibernate annotations to automatically generate UUID's for objects.
Each object gets its own directory on a fileserver, which is named by the generated UUID of the object.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@NotNull
@Column(name = "m_uuid")
private String mUUID;
```

The UUID is the only field that let's you identify an object for sure. Is there a way to get the generated values back after persisting the object, **without creating a new query**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nee to persist and flush the persistence context:

```
entityManager.persist(entity);
entityManager.flush();
entity.getId();
```

This way the entity is guaranteed to be attached and the only statement that is executed is the INSERT one so no need for a query statement.

Comment: I also just realized that the ID will be saved to the object after persisting it. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: But you also need the flush, because that's when the state changes are synchronized with the database.